# error 2013 (hy000) lost connection to mysql server during query while load of mysqldump

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, errors, mysqladmin

I'm trying to load `mysqldump` and I keep getting following error:

> ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line X: Lost connection to MySQL server during
>   query

`/etc/my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 16M
net_read_timeout = 30
net_write_timeout = 60
...
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet = 16M
```

I tried to increase these values, but I keep getting that error no matter what( What else can I do to overcome this error?

Comment: Set the value in the `[mysql]` section of the config, as well? (Not `[mysqladmin]` though).  `SELECT @@MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET;` to confirm that the server is using these values?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I did typo, I meant to write `mysqldump` (not `mysqldadmin`), should I just keep `max_allowed_packet` or add `net_read_timeout` & `net_write_timeout` as well?

Answer (score 11):

If all the other solutions here fail - check your syslog (/var/log/syslog or similar) to see if your server is running out of memory during the query.

Had this issue when innodb_buffer_pool_size was set too close to physical memory without a swapfile configured. MySQL recommends for a database specific server setting innodb_buffer_pool_size at a max of around 80% of physical memory, I had it set to around 90%, the kernel was killing the mysql process. Moved innodb_buffer_pool_size back down to around 80% and that fixed the issue.

Comment: Good hint! Checked /var/log/messages and indeed found the issue here! memory shortage.

Comment: For AWS RDS users - Try just changing instance type to one with more memory - worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

The error code **ERROR 2013 (HY000)** 
related with aborted connection. You can run the following command to verify this.

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE  'Aborted_connects';
```

If the counter getting increased one by each attempt to connect, then it is an issue with connection.

One way to solve this issue, you can increase the connection timeout value in your configuration file. You can do that by using the following command.

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL connect_timeout = 10;
```

I hope this will help you. Thank you.

Comment: right after I got error, I checked for `Aborted_connects` and it shows me `0`.

Comment: Mine was close, but this gave me the hint: I needed to check for Aborted_clients instead, but this worked as I checked by using `"SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE  '%Aborted%';"` which by coincidence showed both Aborted values.

Answer (score 1):

@A_funs was right, inspecting the system log yields this:

```
Aug 14 08:04:15 centos-php55 kernel: Killed process 8597 (mysqld) total-vm:7395680kB, anon-rss:3351108kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Aug 14 08:04:15 centos-php55 mysqld_safe[7848]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 200:  8597 Killed                  LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libjemalloc.so.1 nohup /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log --open-files-limit=1024000 --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1
```

So it might very well be possible you're (like me) running out of memory on the machine. My problem was that MySQL was using too much memory so the scheduler was killing the process. Actually lowering `innodb_buffer_pool_size` fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. How does it differ from previous answers? Because OP stated *I'm not running out of memory and my innodb_buffer_pool_size IS set to 80%*.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice OPs answer. Oh well, might as well leave it here.

Comment: I agree with @hot2use that your answer as posted isn't really adding much new value, and given how much later you've posted it, it might also be a little confusing as it kind of invalidates the OP's comment (which has been there for a long time too) saying that theirs *wasn't* a memory issue. On the other hand, if the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` value that fixed the problem for you had to be lower than the recommended 80%, maybe you could add that to your answer (specifying the actual value you set it to), cheers.

Comment: I down-vote this answer as that's a copy of someone else already wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

What command are you using to load mysqldump?
Is this a production server? 
Size of the dump? 
Format of the dump (.gz or .sql)?

Check if the error caused due to restart,if yes
1) check mysql memory allocation
2) try to reduce memory allocation by reducing innodb_buffer_pool size

This will help to reduce swap usage.

Comment: Yes. Just reduced innodb_buffer_pool_size from 4GB to 3GB , and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was using vagrant and had allocated just 768M of memory to the mysql -virtual machine. I increased the memory to 4096M and it worked again.